# Kendo Grid Add/Remove Columns

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a **Kendo** grid which has a lot of columns.
At the initial loading, only a few columns are displayed since I used the `hidden` attribute on Grid options.

```
{ field: 'projDisplayId', title: "columnToBeDisplayed", width: "170px"},

{ field: 'workTypDescription', hidden: true, title: "hiddenColumn", width: "170px" },
```

After that, I manually added some other columns by checking them on the column menu (see [My Kendo Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwKsg.png))
However, when I refresh the page, the columns I added before the refresh have disappeared.

Is there any way to keep the added columns displayed even after I refresh the page?

Comment: Store the column state when changes are made somewhere/anywhere and apply the state after the page is loaded.  There is nothing built into the grid that will remember the previous state after a complete page reload.  This is same thing as entering data into a form and refreshing the page without saving it...it does not just magically get remembered.

Comment: In my script, I can detect the Show/hide event but I don't have any idea to where to store the states.   
columnHide: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.column.field); 
},                                                                                                 columnShow: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.column.field);  },

Comment: I find a way to store the columns states on the local storage and it works fine. I think after that i'll add a feature to store grid's settings  on my database and load them after. This will help me to have more than one custom grids. Thank you for your help :)